# java project external jar location

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a java project. in the java build path it points to external jars that reside on a location on my c drive. Now i want to stage this project on builforge that doesnt allow components to be on c drive. How can i externalize so that the external jar file location can be a variable so that 
the jar can reside on a different location.

when i do a build from the new machine, it errors out saying the required libraries are misssing in c drive.

At compile time on my machine the project expects the jars to be on c: while on buildforge i need to make the project ignore the c: location and take the E: location instead.

i tried addvariables and other options all those options still expects me to give a path.

Comment: Why don't you copy the jar to a folder inside your project and reference them as internal jars and not external?

Comment: @JP the problem with that approach is that the jars get built up as part of the deployable unit and makes it unneccasarily big. We dont want to package these jars along with the deploybale unit. We just want them to reside somewhere on the machine

Comment: Well then you can reference the jar via a workspace variable and have it take different values on different machines.

Comment: @JP how do i do that? I have an option to created a variable, i create one called EXT_JARS and then pointed it to c:/temp/ext_jars. I guess it would be the same if created a variable called workspace it would still point to c:/temp/ext_jars. it still fails when i stage it and says c:/temp... libray not found

Comment: A variable is workspace specific, so define a different value in your build machine workspace. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: @JP i think we are referring to two different things. I am talking about the variable that is project specific in my eclipse project. I right click on my eclipse project and add the external jars and in this case created a project specific variable called EXT_JARS to point to c:/temp/ext_jars.  If i dont specify the external jars at the project level, i get compile errors. I dont think i can just set the jars in classpath at the workspace level. Hopefully i am making sense.

Comment: In your project build path, if you choose "add variable" you can add a new variable. These ClassPath variables are workspace specific, not project specific. We use that all the time for projects referencing jars that may not always be in the same location.

Comment: @JP ok, so if i set the variable to c:/temp/ext_jars and now when i stage the prject on a machine that doesn't have this. How will i make it point to e:/temp/ext_jars for example? The error i get is very specific, it just doesnt say class not found. it says c:/temp/ext_jars library not found. Hopefully you are not tired of explaining it.

Comment: I only know about Eclipse, what do you do on your build machine? Do you have eclipse there as well, or do you just run the built jar? In the first case, you need to set up the variable in Eclipse to your different location. In the second case, you need to build the jar with relative paths in its manifest.

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: Sorry, I don't have the 'correct' answer to your question but I'm posting it anyway as it could make your or someone else's live easier in a situation like this.

If you don't have any drive E: on your system or if you can rename it without breaking anything, you could create a folder on your C: drive like:

c:\path\to\your\dev\folder\buildforge

and than map it as drive E: like this:

net use e: \localhost\c$\path\to\your\dev\folder\buildforge /persistent:yes

Than you could just create a subdirectory structure on your new E: drive mirroring the one from your buildforge environment and use it in your projects. That way, you wouldn't need to change anything when moving the project.

This approach has obvious advantages as well as disadvantages so it's up to you to decide which of these prevail in your situation. I use this approach to be able to access one shared folder from my host computer as well as from a virtual machine in a uniform way.